# What does "Mail Enabled Sub-domain check failed" mean?

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, smtpclient

I am receiving the message "Mail Enabled Sub-domain check failed" when attempting to send emails via our internal SMTP server.

I am using the SMTP Client library in a VS2013 development environment. I've inherited the code and due to the confidential information contained in the actual configuration, unfortunately I am not at liberty to post it; but I can affirm that the settings for the SMTP Client are correct and I may be able to provide any additional information if it helps to answer the question as long as it doesn't require confidential data.

In past configurations, I have always authenticated directly to a specifically named SMTP server by providing the host and port information in the SMTPClient class instantiation.

This scenario is somewhat different because I've been informed that one of our other servers (A Web Server) where the application is running; is actually being passed as the SMTP Host for the SMTP Client connection.

But in actuality, I'd say it would technically be functioning as a Relay Server since it isn't an SMTP server.

Messages are submitted to our internal staff from the clients through a Popup Dialog that allows them to enter their message and click submit. The message gets sent to an internal email address and CC'd to the sender.

Upon debugging the program, no errors get thrown on the Send() method of the client.

I've tested this and the message must be hitting the SMTP server because I do get an email; however, instead of receiving the test message that I submit via the application; I get a message stating, "Delivery to the following recipients failed." with my email address in it and the email to where the message should be sent.

At the end of the message it says "Mail Enabled Sub-domain check failed"

I've searched online for this message but get no hits so it may be a message that is generated only within our organization; or maybe no one has posted the problem before.

In either case, can anyone provide any insight as to what this message likely means? I receive no errors in the System or Application event logs on the server. Maybe there are some other areas I need to check to make certain the Web server is properly configured to function as an SMTP relay server? I am unfamiliar with configuring a Web Server in this manner.

I'm at a loss for clues at this point.

Comment: Why do you have this marked exchange server? Is there an Exchange server in there somewhere? Can you give an example of the email? Is it a virtual sub-domain set up on a different server, like somebody@sub.domain.com?

Comment: It would also help to post the actual fail email you get as its telling you the destination server refused it.. So, your sending worked...

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes Ron, the configuration is setup to run against an Exchange Server. I probably should have included that in the description of the problem. The Exchange server is not a virtual sub-domain but the Web server which is acting as an SMTP relay to the actual Exchange SMTP server is on a sub-domain. But that is an interesting suggestive question you proposed.

Comment: @BugFinder I agree that the sending portion of the process worked, which prompted me to focus on other areas of the configuration such as the Exchange server

Comment: At this point we believe we've identified the issue so there is not any longer a need to answer the question. However, if SO doesn't have a problem with it; I will likely post the solution once we've affirmed resolution of the problem in the event that someone else may receive the error. Apparently its not a very common error though. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark If you've solved your own question, it is highly encouraged to post it as an answer (and even mark it as the accepted answer). This is because people may have similar problems later and want to know the answer that fixed the problem, obscure or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer as it pertained to our particular situation. I'm fairly certain that the message may be somewhat of a blanket error; and so there may be other scenario's for which the error could be generated.

As previously stated, the SMTP host address that our application is using is actually the host address of the Web Server on which the application is running. The Web Server is also configured as an SMTP relay server, meaning any mail requests sent via the application uses the local host to relay the message to the actual SMTP Exchange Server.

After hours of troubleshooting to find the cause of the error it was identified that the Server Name was not in the correct format to leverage the SMTP Relay system.

For example, the host name that was used was in the format:
machinenameCNameAlias.subdomain.domain.com

when it should have been
actualMachineName.subdomain.domain.com

In other words, the use of a CNAME alias was not valid when using an SMTP Relay Server. (At least in our configuration)

Once the CNAME alias was replaced with the actual name of the server, the error was resolved.

I am obviously not an expert in any respect with the particulars of Exchange or it's Configuration counter parts; but after searching online with the keywords, "CNames and SMTP Relay Servers"; I did find other potential references; maybe inferring that CNAME aliases are discouraged with similar configuration types.

If anyone else can affirm these observations, that would be great.

But as for the particular scenario for which the question was initially posted, this was the answer for us.